# Node.js - Stripe issued card

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to send money from my stripe main balance to issued card.
I was able to create cardholder and card using this doc
https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/cards
But can not find a way to send money to issued card.

Answer (score 1):

Top-Ups come from your bank account, not your Stripe Balance: https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/funding/balance